# Session duration look strange

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I have intergrated Google Analytics in unity project. I see a strange problem. 11 page views and 42 events has been logged in a session. That mean user use the app normally. Problem is duration session's too short. Just 5 seconds. I think duration session is wrong. Please help me explain what happen in my case.

[image: Sample]

Comment: I don't know enough about how Unity handles internet connections but I suspect it's something like: that Unity is opening the connection, passing the data as you've programmed and then closing the connection -- it is *not* a browser where the connection is kept open for the user to view infinitum.

Comment: We also can't really help you much without seeing how your sessions are set up and how your Unity Project connects to the net and sends/requests information from it.